# Batch login system

Tags: batch-file, authentication, system

Hi guys i would like to make a batch (register-login) programm,
What i have so far there are two files called clientdata.bat and data.txt.
What i want is a code that reads the data.txt file, looks for a password and procceds to the login. My code is this.

```
:register
set /p regname= Name:
echo.
set /p regpass= Password:
cls
echo %regname% %regpass% >> data.txt
```

This works perfectly, when it comes to saving data to data.txt file.
But my problem is in the login sector

```
:login    
cls
set /p logname= Name:
echo.
set /p logpass= Password:
```

This is what i have so far in the login section. PLease help!!

Comment: Is there anything you have tried already to retrieve the data and match the inputs to it? Showing effort towards a solution will help other users knowing what you've already tried and piggyback on it rather than spinning code out of nothing.

This being said, password storage is a huge topic and storing in plaintext is frowned upon as a practice even if it's a project just for fun. Bad habit to get into.

Comment: i tried to do this... set /a name =< data.txt 
and then
if not %name% == %logpass% goto wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for /f` to parse data.txt:

```
:login    
cls
set /p logname= Name:
echo.
set /p logpass= Password:

call :authenticate
if %errorlevel% equ 1 echo Wrong password & goto error
if %errorlevel% equ 2 echo No such user & goto error
echo Authenticated successfully
pause
exit

:error
echo format c:
pause
exit

:authenticate
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%u in (data.txt) do (
    if "%%u"=="%logname%" (
        if "%%v"=="%logpass%" exit /b 0
        exit /b 1
    )
)
exit /b 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a system that uses an online PHP mysql database. The php codes would check passwords and add users and stuff. I based it all on this little powershell script you can call using this command: Powershell "& ""%cd%\RespondURL.ps1""" after putting the url you want to load and get a text response from in a text file `urls.txt`. The response is stored in `out.txt` and you can use Find and errorlevel handling to read it, or just use `set /p response=<out.txt`. Its over the top but its great if you want to update it and manage it online.
Note that it requires your Powershell execution policy to be unrestricted. Here is the script:

```
$cur="C:\users\Public"
$contents = Get-Content $cur\urls.txt
$num=1
foreach($content in $contents){
$stat=(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$content").Content
echo $stat$num |Out-File -FilePath $cur\out.txt -Append
$num=$num + 1
}
echo $error.count |Out-File -FilePath $cur\Errors.txt
```

If the script encounters errors, it will put a number over 0 in the file `Errors.txt`